# CountDownTimer на реальном устройстве

Tags: android

Почему на эмуляторе обратный таймер работает, а на реальном устройстве по нулям показывает?
Нигде не могу найти ответ

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setLenient(false);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
long data = (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE))*60 +   cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
***
// по алгоритму считаю h m s
String oldTime = "" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
Date oldDate;
try {
  oldDate = formatter.parse(oldTime);
   milliseconds = oldDate.getTime();
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
   //Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "milliseconds" + milliseconds);
MyCount counter = new MyCount(milliseconds,1000);
counter.start();
 return myFragmentView;
}
 public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
 public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
     super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
 }

 @Override
 public void onFinish() {

 }

 @Override
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     Long serverUptimeSeconds = 
             (millisUntilFinished) / 1000;
     String serverUptimeText = 
         String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
         ( serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600 ,
         ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600 ) / 60,
         ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600 ) % 60
         );

         textTimer.setText(serverUptimeText);
 }
 }
```